# how to set fixed size for circle animation to all screen sized in android

Tags: android

fixed size circle aniamtion problem

hello there , i have this class :

```
 public circle (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {


    super(context, attrs);

    final int strokeWidth = 30;

    paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

    //Circle color

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);


    //size 200x200 example

    rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 350 + strokeWidth, 350 +

    strokeWidth);


    //Initial Angle (optional, it can be zero)

    angle = 0;
}

@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);



}

public float getAngle() {

    return angle;
}

public void setAngle(float angle) {

    this.angle = angle;

}



}
```

and this class is responsible for animation draw circle

the animation class is :

```
public class CircleAngleAnimation extends Animation {

private circle circle;

private float oldAngle;

private float newAngle;

public CircleAngleAnimation(circle circle, int newAngle) {

this.oldAngle = circle.getAngle();

this.newAngle = newAngle;

this.circle = circle;
}

@Override

protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation

transformation) {  

float angle = oldAngle + ((newAngle - oldAngle) * interpolatedTime);

circle.setAngle(angle);

circle.requestLayout();

}


}
```

i attached xml value in my mainactivity.xml to the circle class like this :

```
       <com.mynetwork.zaidkhaled.speech.circle
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

in mainactivity i set animation = new CircleAngleAnimation(circle, 360); animation.setDuration(1000); then i call start animation by circle.startanimation(animation);

now my problem is when this circle is drawn in the activity , if the screen resolution is high it will be drawn perfectly , perfect sized , if the screen resolution is low it will be drawn very very big , how can set this cricle to be drawn in the same size on every mobile device ?
thanks for help :)

Comment: what do you mean format my code?

Comment: Make it readable for human

Comment: can you just please help me? , i cant format my code...\

Comment: its an issue with xml , i tried to add fixed width and height it doesnt work